# How to set nickname discord js error Missing permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

So I'm trying to set nicknames to people with the bot, however it errors out as Missing Permissions

```
C:\Users\EntropicBlackhole\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\EntropicBlackhole\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\EntropicBlackhole\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async GuildMemberManager.edit (C:\Users\EntropicBlackhole\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:279:15) {
  method: 'patch',
  path: '/guilds/758349837657440256/members/708026434660204625',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: {
    json: { nick: 'nickname', communication_disabled_until: undefined },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Why do I get this error? The bot has administrator permissions but I don't really understand why it gives this error

Answer (score 0):

`ADMINISTRATOR` permission to change the nickname of the other person isn't enough, instead you should give the bot `MANAGE_NICKNAMES` and `CHANGE_NICKNAME` permissions, but if you want to restrict others from accessing your command, add this:

```js
if(!<User>.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_NICKNAMES && Permissions.FLAGS.CHANGE_NICKNAME)) return message.reply({ content: `you dont have enough permission to use this command` })
```

**For more information about Discord Permissions: [Discord Permissions](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions)**

Comment: i did manually give it manage nicknames and then the change nicknames permissions, but still nothing, so i kicked the bot and used the link that had basically all the permissions placed into it, but it still isn't working

Comment: Can you show me your command code, and your client intents?

Comment: `const member = msg.guild.members.cache.get(msg.author.id)
      var nickname = capitalizeWords(temp)
      member.roles.add(roleCountry);
      member.roles.remove(roleNonCountry);
      member.setNickname("test");
      msg.reply(`"${capitalizeWords(temp)}" has been granted as your country!`)
      country.Amount += 1`

Comment: `const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES] });`

Comment: everything works, only that member.setNickname gives error, it's not member because member.roles works correctly, so its definitely the intents, what intent should i add there?

Comment: bro- i didnt really meant to "send" it literally HERE, i was saying upload it into, https://sourceb.in or smthing and send it here. that code is totally unreadable here

Comment: sorry about that, [here](https://sourceb.in/ixGAEu2XFm)

Comment: what intents do i need to add?

Comment: try adding these intents: 
GUILD_UPDATE,
GUILD_MEMBER_UPDATE

Comment: `const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_UPDATE, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBER_UPDATE] });` i added it but it doesn't seem to work